# To to Edit > Copy the diagram generated by Mermaid when using the Mermaid plugin in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, copy, mermaid

I am using the [Mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/) diagramming and charting tool to generate an ERD diagram. I access Mermaid within [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE through the [Mermaid plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20146-mermaid) provided by [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains).

I am using the dual-pane mode, with my markup text on the left, and the generated diagram visible on the right side.

How does one export, print, or copy that generated diagram?

I can find no menus, buttons, or context menu items to accomplish these common tasks.

Comment: It's not supported so far, you may create a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. Now you can use Mermaid Live Editor https://mermaid.live/ as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Comment by Jacky Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77467042/to-to-edit-copy-the-diagram-generated-by-mermaid-when-using-the-mermaid-plugin?noredirect=1#comment136592637_77467042) confirms there is no such feature.

### Print to PDF

As a workaround for the lack of a Edit > Copy command, you can on a Mac:

1. Click once in the empty background of the diagram.
2. Choose File > Print.
3. Navigate the Print dialogs to generate a PDF document.
4. Open that PDF in an app such as *Preview*, and copy.

## *mermaid-cli*

Another avenue is using the [*mermaid-cli*](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli) command-line interface tool to generate an svg/png/pdf file .

Comment: Nice workaround! I also use Mermaid. A good thing is that its script is compatible with plantUML i.e. you can use its script in plantUML as-it-is or with a minor change. I like both tools equally.